# laravel gulp not working as expected

Tags: laravel, gulp, gulp-sass

i am not a gulp and laravel expert, im just learning how it works, im following the tutorial on laracast, and something strange is happening, i put this inside my app.scss

```
// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

$color:red;

body{
    color:$color
}
```

**and on gulpfile i have this:**

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
```

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

but somehow, when i run gulp on cmd, i get a app.css with like 5000 lines of code, and not just my style that i defined :S, i get something like this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0; }

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block; }

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0; }

[hidden],
template {
  display: none; }
```

dunno what is happening if someone can give me a advice i appreciate :D

Comment: This is just the Bootstrap CSS that you're importing on your very first line, no?

Comment: yes but in the video the guy has the line to import that bootstrap to, without it i dont get anything :S

Comment: With sass you compile everything from bootstrap sass library into your own generated .css file. So in the bottom you can see your own css. You don't need to include bootstrap.css as separated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of code

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

in your app.scss file.

Gulp is adding that bootstrap file also in your final result.
It's a normal behavior.

Comment: thanks, strange that the guy on the video got his own css even with the bootstrap include :S